# SHA256 signature Method for XML files not working on Windows Server 2003

Tags: xml, xml-signature

I use the some program on Windows Server 2003. The database is loaded into this program as an XML file. Everything worked correctly until the developers changed the XML signature from sha1 to sha256.

Is there a way to convert SHA256 signature to SHA1 or another way to read an XML file with the SHA256 signature in the program used.

I installed the kb3072630 update on Windows Server 2003, but it didn't help.

Comment: Do not know for sure.  You may be able to use powershell or OpenSSL

Comment: Are you trying to validate the data using the sha256 hash or are you simply loading data into the database where one of the fields used to be a sha1 hash but is now a sha256 hash.?  If you're trying to load a sha256 hash into a field That was originally sized for a Sha1ne hash you will need to increase the size of the field in your database.